# Running CRON job on Ubuntu server for SugarCRM

Tags: cron

I am pretty inexperienced in Linux, so be descriptive on your answer.

My environment: Local Linux server 12.04 hosting Sugar CRM 6.5.2.

There is area in sugar CRM called scheduler. I can configured some predefined jobs here. in my case i am trying to run email reminders (ever min/hour/day/month). For this scheduler to be effective, i read some where i need to setup CRON job. So I did some research & finally put following lines in CRONTAB for the root user, as per instructions given in sugarCRM.

`* * * * * cd /var/www/crm; php -f cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Well I am creating contracts in my sugarCRM (AOS module) & I want email reminders to be sent for these contracts to the concern person. Now my sugarCRM email is configured correctly & I can send test emails using it. But the CRON + scheduler not giving any result. I can't receive any emails.

Then I tried to read /var/log/syslog & it is showing entry for following line each minute.

> Oct 27 15:03:01 unicomm CRON[28182]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/crm; php -f cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1)

I've few questions:

1. what does the CRON job line i've added in crontab mean? `cd /var/www/crm; php -f cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1` is not making any sense to me.
2. How am i suppose to get this thing work? I've searched a lot (including SugarCRM forum), but no luck.

Comment: If you run the cron job right from the command line, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

The line in the crontab just executes the command `cd /var/www/crm; php -f cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`. What this command actually does is that, it changes the current working directory to `/var/www/crm` and tries to execute the `cron.php` file there using the php interpreter. The output and errors are redirected to `/dev/null`, ie, they're discarded.

If you want the emails to be sent, you have to check if the cron.php is actually having code to send emails and whether that code is getting executed.

Answer (score -1):

I have just landed here because I have the same problem. 
And it's a misunderstanding: You DON'T have to execute 
*    *    *    *    *  cd /var/www/html/SuiteCRM-7.6.4; php -f cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1 
You HAVE to add this line to the crontab file

Execute: sudo crontab -e

Choose your favorite editor, and add the line at the end (the 5 stars * are required)

Save